# Make view round after autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a `tableview` with custom cells which are built from `storyboard` with an identifier using `AutoLayout`.

One of the `subviews` needs to be round `(layer.cornerRadius = width/2)`, it is a square in the beginning.

I have tried in `layoutSubviews()` but it seems to be called before `AutoLayout` changes its size... same thing for `didMoveToSuperview()`

Where is the proper function to update things like this to my subviews after `AutoLayout` has changed their sizes?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell_small") as! Cell
    ...
    return cell
}

// In Cell

override func layoutSubviews() {
    rankLabel.layer.cornerRadius = rankLabel.bounds.width/2
    rankLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    rankLabel.layer.cornerRadius = rankLabel.bounds.width/2
    rankLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: have you tried in cellForRowAtIndexPath method ?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called before layout, see my answer below, you can use willDisplayCell

Comment: use
  rankLabel.clipsToBounds=YES;

Comment: if I print out rankLabel's size it is the wrong size for everything Ive tried. But If I swipe the tableview then it calls the updatefunctions and the size is right.

Comment: Ive had lots of problem with autolayout before if I want a round subview...

Comment: I guess everything is right. Its just the width of the UILabel that might cause this problem. Do check width of the the label by putting break point in layoutSubviews()

Comment: @somexyz Its actually a label with backgroundcolor and cornerRadius

Comment: Try using this "rankLabel.layer.cornerRadius = rankLabel.bounds.height/2" instead of "rankLabel.layer.cornerRadius = rankLabel.bounds.width/2"

Comment: @somexyz Ive already tried it. I have width and height constraints on it, the label without these constraints wants to be bigger snd the problem is that att the point when the class reaches layoutSubviews() autolayout havny changed its size yet.

Comment: Same problem here, any updates? I added that 2 lines of code in `- (void) layoutSubviews`. It worked, but at a while after the cell has been displayed so that there is an obvious shape change.

Comment: You have to subclass every view you want to change the shape of and then inside its layoutSubviews you do the shape.

Comment: @LordSpark Check my answer I just made.

Comment: @Arbitur Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this one **working** in my case .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362934/how-to-keep-a-round-imageview-round-using-auto-layout/43998774#43998774

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I ended up doing was making a class called `RoundView`

```
class RoundView:UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width/2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

And then I apply it to every view I need to be round. So in Storyboard I add `RoundView` to `Custom Class`.

What was happening was that if you look inside the source of the storyboard (XML) every view had the size of the whole screen, you can look inside your own SB code. So by trying to add a corner radius equal to the `width/2` inside its parent `layoutSubviews()` that subview hasn't got its frame set correctly. So the corner radius got the value of `320/2` instead of `50/2`, thats why it got misshaped.

Answer (score 3):

1.Create a custom class of UIView/category

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RoundView : UIView

@end
#import "RoundView.h"
```

2.Add layoutSubviews method and set corner radius.

```
@implementation RoundView

-(void)layoutSubviews{

[super layoutSubviews];

self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/2;

self.layer.masksToBounds = true;

}
```

3.Make your UIView as a subclass of RoundView and run the application, you can see circle view.

Answer (score 1):

Try subclassing UITableViewCell like this,

```
@interface RoundingCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel * someLabel;

@end

@implementation RoundingCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.someLabel.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(self.someLabel.bounds)/2;
    self.someLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

@end
```

And Use this as the class of the desired cell, along with IBOutlet connections.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my imageview so i resolved it by sub-classing UIImageView.

```
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView

@end
```

---

```
@implementation MyImageView

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];    
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, I make my round cells just by using your code. (and I also use auto layout).

The only difference is, I use .`frame` and not .`bounds`  (divided by 2). Have you tried that?

Otherwise you can use a custom cell and in the -`awakeFromNib` set rounding the same way, so you don't have to do it in each cell.

Comment: I do have it structured like this: contentView->UIView->UILabel So maybe i need to subclass that UIView and in awakeFromNib or layoutSubViews make UILabel round there?

Comment: if you have a Label in a view, then you must have `IBOutlets` that you can use.
Something like `cell.myView.layer.frame.width/2`  should do the job. Not forgetting the mask of course.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1. Create a custom Class YourCell and add your code to the initWithCoder-Method
2. Add a method to your ViewController

like following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and change it inside there. To access the cell you call

```
[(YourCell *)cell view]....
```

Comment: Neither worked :( And I dont think iniWithCoder would ever work because it is called before anything else :P