# Why UIImageView doesn't display rounded until scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cornerradius

My `UIImageView` doesn't appear rounded util scrolling or reload the collection view (`collectionView.reloadData()`).

This is how it looks:

- Without rounding

[image]

- With rounding

[image]

The cell has multiple image views and all of them are constrained to go with `facesContainer` UIView constrains.

I tried to implement this code is inside `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` :

```
cell.facesContainer.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.facesContainer.layer.frame.width/2)
cell.facesGroupImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.facesGroupImageView.layer.frame.width/2)
cell.facesGroupImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.facesGroupImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.facesGroupImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
```

Also, I tried to add the code snippet above in the custom cell class, at `awakeFromNib()` method, but it doesn't work.

Why it doesn't work? how to fix it?

Comment: did u try this in willdisplaycell method

Comment: Constraints are not present in `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Take a look at this post - explanation and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362934/how-to-keep-a-round-imageview-round-using-auto-layout

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put your codes inside this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // your view configurations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting radius in viewWillLayoutSubviews will solve the problem.

`override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
  profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height / 2.0
}`